# HyperlinkButton inside Text Block

Tags: c#, wpf, json, xaml, hyperlink

There is some text that i want to take from JSON file:

```
"text":"evqvqgqegweg<br>wegewg<br>e<br>ewgewg<br>ewg<br>http:\/\/f.com<br>egewg"
```

How can I detect the link and parse it to the textblock with `HyperlinkButton`?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066725/wpf-listbox-with-file-hyperlink-mvvm/19071322#19071322)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression to pick out your links: `http:.*[.com|.co.uk]` This will of course also parse any escape characters: `http:\/\/f.com`.

You can use it like this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(inputTextString, "http:.*[.com|.co.uk]");
if (match.Success) PublicLinkProperty = new Uri(match.Value);
```

Where `PublicLinkProperty` is a property on your view model/code behind:

```
// you should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on this property
public Uri PublicLinkProperty { get; set; }
```

You can then use that property to `Bind` to the `HyperlinkButton.NavigateUri` property:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Click here" NavigateUri="{Binding PublicLinkProperty}" 
    TargetName="_blank" />
```

Note that this regular expression will pick out *anything* that starts with `http:` and ends with either `.com` or `.co.uk`.